# Swapping cell data gives unique constraint violation, although overall changes are valid

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

The following use case gives an unnecessary unique constraint violation, most likely because the changes are checked row by row instead of altogether:

1. Given: a table in an Oracle database of the following form:

> Name   |  Order
>
> name1 |    1
>
> name2 |    2

where Order has a unique constraint.

2. This table is presented to the user, using a DataGridView, like this:

   ```
   this.myDataGridView.DataSource = this.mydataSet;
   this.myTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDataSet.myTableName);
   this.myDataSet.AcceptChanges();
   ```
3. The user swaps the two values within the table. The table now looks like this:

> Name  |  Order
>
> name1 |    2
>
> name2 |    1

4. The user tries to save the changes in the database. The corresponding code looks like this:

   ```
   this.myTableAdapter.Update(this.myDataSet.myTableName);
   ```

Result: I get a unique Constraint violation (ORA-00001).

I already tried the following solutions:

A) Encapulation the command in a transaction like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  this.myTableAdapter.Update(this.myDataSet.myTableName);
  scope.Complete();
}
```

B) Using BeginEdit and EndEdit on all rows or all changed rows, like this:

```
DataTable dtChanges = this.myDataSet.myTableName.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
DataRowCollection changedRows = dtChanges.Rows;

foreach (DataRow currRow in dtChanges.Rows)
{
  currRow.BeginEdit();
}

this.myTableAdapter.Update(this.myDataSet.myTableName);

foreach (DataRow currRow in dtChanges.Rows)
{
  currRow.EndEdit();
}
```

C) Switching off Constraints checking, like this:

```
this.myDataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;

this.myTableAdapter.Update(this.myDataSet.myTableName);

this.myDataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

none of which solved my problem, the exception keeps coming.

Does anyone know how to make this swap possible, if possible without removing the constraint altogether?

**Update 1:**

This is even stranger: even when I explicitly clear all constraints of the datatable using

```
this.myDataSet.myTableName.Constraints.Clear();
```

I still get a constraint violation. Could it be that the database doesn't give a damn about what I specify in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle validates constraint not row-by-row, but on statement basis.
So if you make this swap by single UPDATE statement you will not get error:

```
-- table with constraint
CREATE TABLE tab (NAME VARCHAR2(200), order_ NUMBER);
ALTER TABLE tab ADD (CONSTRAINT test_uk UNIQUE (order_));
-- initial data population
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('name1',1);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('name2',2);
COMMIT;
```

you may check that constraint works ;)

```
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('name3',1); -- this will fail
```

Now you may swap values by single UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tab SET order_ = DECODE(order_,1,2,2,1) WHERE order_ IN (1,2);
```

this will work fine

```
SELECT * FROM tab;
```

**DEFERRED constraint checking**
You may also check constraint not for each statement but for whole transaction.
In such case you need to recreate constraint as DEFERRABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE tab DROP CONSTRAINT test_uk CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tab ADD (CONSTRAINT test_uk UNIQUE (order_) DEFERRABLE);
```

Let's repopulate this table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tab;
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('name1',1);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('name2',2);
COMMIT;
```

Such statement will fail, because of constraint:

```
UPDATE tab SET order_ = 2 WHERE NAME = 'name1';
```

But if you set constraint as deferred, same statement will not failed until commit

```
SET CONSTRAINT test_uk DEFERRED;
UPDATE tab SET order_ = 2 WHERE NAME = 'name1';
```

Commit will validate constraint and will fail

```
COMMIT; -- this will fail now
```

But if we swap orders, commit succeeds because constraint is not violated now:

```
SET CONSTRAINT test_uk DEFERRED;
UPDATE tab SET order_ = 2 WHERE NAME = 'name1';
UPDATE tab SET order_ = 1 WHERE NAME = 'name2';
COMMIT;
```

And gives desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM tab;
```

Comment: I try to keep the logic in C#, not Oracle - in which way do I have to change the Update call to make the Update a single statement?

Comment: Changing the Constraint type to Deferred alone did not change the result, exception is still on. What am I missing?

Comment: Check the actual state of the constraint. Because it can be initially immediate or deferred. If it's initially immediate then it needs to be set to deferred before you start DML. Also read about deferred constraints because they bring some consequences you might be not aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - did some reading on the issue, will do some more in the next days. Regarding the issue itself: If I change the constraint to deferred, initially deferred, I still get the same error - with an additional "ORA-02091 transaction rolled back" error tacked on.

Comment: Can you trace database calls that your application does?

Comment: "ORA-02091 transaction rolled back" usually returned when constraint check fails on commit. So you have inconsistent state at transaction end.
So you need to check logic of application (how it do swap).
If you have something like this
UPDATE tab SET order_ = 2 WHERE order_ = 1;
UPDATE tab SET order_ = 1 WHERE order_ = 2;
You'll get wrong result (first both orders will be '2', then they both will be 1).

Comment: How do I do database call traces in C#?

Comment: To elaborate: I simply call the Update function on the dataset. I didn't implement the exact logic, and I don't know of a way to log how the program does the update.